# Can't upload any files on Drupal 7 multisite

Tags: file, permissions, drupal-7

I have a multisite Drupal 7 setup. I just noticed that on the one I'm working on, I can't upload any files at all. I tried using the file upload, and IMCE in it's file browser. I just keep getting a generic file can't be uploaded error. I have two other sites on the shared system, and they work fine. I have checked and rechecked all the file permissions and ownerships, and they are exactly the same. All the file settings, permissions, etc. on all three Drupal sites in the admin sections are the same. I'm at a loss of where to look next. The server error logs are no help, as well as the dblog in Drupal. Any ideas would be great because I've been looking at this for too long now.

Comment: Just to be clear, I can upload files using FTP. The problem comes when I try to upload from inside Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I fixed this finally. The solution still doesn't seem to make any sense, but it works. I had to change the group ownership to apache instead of the default Plesk owner. The other sites work with the group owner as Plesk, so it doesn't make sense to me. At least it works.